# Neo4j import relations

Tags: neo4j

I use Neo4j Community Edition 4.0.4 on CentOS 7.

Is it possible to load relations to db with neo4j-admin tool **from the same .csv**  file as I load nodes?
Because I have all data in one MSSQL table, which I upload to .csv with bcp utility.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You best bet in that case would probably be to use Cypher's [LOAD CSV](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/load-csv/) directly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have very large amount of data

Comment: Does using periodic commits help? https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/load-csv/#load-csv-setting-the-rate-of-periodic-commits

Comment: Yes, it help! Thank you! 20 million nodes with 8 properties each  from 1.8 Gb .csv file per 210 seconds! I think it's really cool. I know, there are core limitations to use data science algorothms in community ed.(I can use only 4 cores), but are there any core limitations to loadcsv command?

Comment: Not entirely sure. You can also improve your batch insertion execution by setting proper indices and constraints (that will speed up the MERGE statements).